# Task closing with continuous sine signal

Tags: python, nidaqmx

I wanted to use a NI card USB-6216 to generate a continuous sinus signal via analog output for a long time (hours, until my measurements are done) and in my measurement routine, I also wanted to read my analog inputs.

My questions are now:

- Is this in general possible to read analog inputs while generating an analog output signal?
- How can I close my task in a right way? In my Code example (below), the sinus signal works fine but I can't rewrite my NI card because I get the error:

> DaqError: Wait Until Done did not indicate that the task was done
> within the specified timeout. Increase the timeout, check the program,
> and make sure connections for external timing and triggering are in
> place. Task Name: _unnamedTask<2E3E1>
>
> Status Code: -200560

Code example:

```
import nidaqmx
import numpy as np
from nidaqmx.constants import AcquisitionType

SamplesPerSignal = 100
SignalFrequency = 1000
NumberOfCycles = 100000000
Amplitude=2
w=2*np.pi*SamplesPerSignal
Sample = np.linspace(0,SamplesPerSignal,num=SamplesPerSignal)
Signal= np.sin(Sample*w)*Amplitude

task = nidaqmx.Task()
task.ao_channels.add_ao_voltage_chan("Dev1/ao0")
task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(rate= SignalFrequency*SamplesPerSignal, sample_mode= AcquisitionType.CONTINUOUS, samps_per_chan=SamplesPerSignal*NumberOfCycles)
writer = nidaqmx.stream_writers.AnalogSingleChannelWriter(task.out_stream, auto_start=True)
writer.write_many_sample(Signal)
```